# What is wrong with my paypal process to receive webhook notifications?

Tags: paypal

So this is what i did so far and it doesn't work, i will appreciate any help on the matter:

my goal is to post back any webhook event that occur in my paypal sandbox account.

So i have 2 accounts, 
one that belongs to the receiver of the money, call it "facilitator",
one that belong to the "buyer",

Now in my account,there is a Sandbox webhooks configuration, so i entered the following:
https://csdieuqkzo.localtunnel.me

goes without saying that this comes from [localtunnel.me](https://localtunnel.me/).

So in my project, i do a simple sale using the api... this is the full create sale process:

```
$payer = new Payer();
 $payer->setPayment_method('paypal');

 //dd($payer);
 $item = new Item();

 $item->setQuantity('1');
 $item->setName('benny');
 $item->setPrice('7.41');
 $item->setCurrency('USD');
 $item->setSku('blah');
 // //var_dump($item);

 $items = new ItemList();
 $items->addItem($item);
 //var_dump($items);

$amountDetails = new Details();
$amountDetails->setSubtotal('7.41');
$amountDetails->setTax('0.03');
$amountDetails->setShipping('0.03');

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD');
$amount->setTotal('7.47');
$amount->setDetails($amountDetails);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);
$transaction->setDescription('This is the payment transaction description.');
$transaction->setItemList($items);

// echo '<pre>';
// print_r($transaction);


$RedirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$RedirectUrls ->setReturnUrl('https://csdieuqkzo.localtunnel.me/#/pricing');
$RedirectUrls ->setCancelUrl('https://csdieuqkzo.localtunnel.me/#/');

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale');
$payment->setPayer($payer);
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));
$payment->setRedirectUrls($RedirectUrls);

// echo '<pre>';
// print_r($payment);
// dd();
$response = $payment->create($this->apiContext)->toarray();

Session::put('pay_id',$response['id']);

return Response::json($response);
```

After this there is a redirect to paypal, approval and when it comes back to my site, it excute with the following:

```
  $payerId =  Input::get('payerId');

$payment = Payment::get(Session::get('pay_id'), $this->apiContext);

//return $payerId;

 $paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution();
 $paymentExecution->setPayer_id($payerId);

 $approval = $payment->execute($paymentExecution, $this->apiContext)->toarray();

 return Response::json($approval);
```

Then an object is coming in saying the state of this transaction is approved, super, but i don't see any post to the webhook url i defined earlier...Now how did i test it?

I wrote a simple script to the post method of my root (in laravel):

```
Route::post('/',function(){
    $myfile = fopen("bennyfile.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
     $txt = "\nouterequested";
     fwrite($myfile, $txt);
     fclose($myfile);
});
```

Means whenever a post request is coming to the following url (in my case, a post to the root of:https://csdieuqkzo.localtunnel.me

I just want to add a line, that's it...but it doesn't update anything!...
for example if i do a post request from postman to the same place, all is good, but when a sale is approved, or any other action, nothing is happening.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is a paypal document which helps you understand how webhooks works.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/

webhooks is http call back mechanism, ideally, you will need a valid url as your webhooks endpoint to test the webhooks notification message posted by PayPal. If you did sale using paypal wallet, you should get PayPal's webhooks notification message in JSON format at your endpoint. webhooks doesn't support direct credit card case yet.

If you want to test your listener script on local, you can use postman tool to post the sample message to your local url and test.

Comment: That's the problem, i don't get any post request to the endpoint, please read what i wrote above for further inquiry

Comment: If this is a sale payment using paypal, only echeck will trigger the webhooks notification for now. The idea behind this is that echeck is not instant funding source, the payment status will be pending initially, and then switched to completed later, at the point, paypal will send webhooks notifications. If you're using instant payment funding source other than echeck, the payment will be processed right away, you should already get the resource in the response when you make REST API call.

Comment: @PayPalAlex In the sandbox environment, completed payments (payment_method: paypal, intent: sale) that are executed immediately go into a `pending` state that require `approval`. I know how to switch this off in the sandbox environment, but my understanding is that this can happen in the live environment as well, so that PayPal can perform their own fraud detection. Is this correct? If so, shouldn't the event in which this fraud detection is completed trigger a webhook event?

Comment: To reinforce what @Matt has said, PayPal clearly state in their webhooks doc that: "Note: Webhook events are delivered only for resource state changes that occur through PayPal’s REST APIs". As far as I understand that means that if a transaction goes from "pending" to "approved" to "completed", a webhook should be sent somewhere along the way. Alex, I couldn't find anywhere in PayPal's docs an indication that this only applies for eCheck payments, where did you see that?

Comment: @Matt, it won't trigger a webhook event if you use funding instruments other than echeck for sale for now.

Comment: @OrPo Unfortunately it was not documented properly. this is a known issue, paypal webhooks team is working on this and will start supporting all funding instruments soon, ETA is next Jan.

Comment: @Alex Thank you. Your responses are better than the off-shore customer support I've been receiving which responds to me as if I am the one who has misread the documentation. I understand it may be in a different department than yours, but a simple note in the REST API that certain features are not yet available would be respectful to the developers who want to use the PayPal REST API so that they don't spend days or weeks in development before hitting these walls. In any case, thanks again.

Comment: @Matt, I will share your feedback with doc team.

Comment: To update this thread, PayPal has added webhooks support to cover all other funding sources for sale payment. Doc also got updated.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/

Answer (score -1):

Using "localhost" isn't going to work because when PayPal's servers hits that address they're just hitting themselves.  You need to setup DNS to point a domain to a virtual server on your local machine instead so that you can use a fully qualified domain name instead of localhost.

Comment: He is using localtunnel.me

Comment: I did read the question carefully, and he said he was using localhost.  It has since been edited with the updated info.  If you look at the edit history you'll see my answer made sense with the original post.