# Paypal RestAPI not firing Webhooks

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, webhooks, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm developping a payment system which is using paypal's rest api.
So far so good, I can do payments in sandbox mode without any problems.

Now I need paypal to notify me on certain events ... which is why I wanted to use webhooks.

I create a little script which just write the received body into a text file to do some debugging. Then I did create the webhook in paypal's dev site. The Webhook simulator is working fine and the json string coming from paypal is fine. However, when I just do a payment through my site, there is no webhook. They don't seem to be called, since it doesn't show any webhook events in developer.paypal.com ...

```
        $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

        $payment = new PPayment();
    $payment->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
```

I'm using the payment method "paypal" and the "sale" intent. That should be working in theory.

Anyone any idea ? I did some research and found that the sandbox is bugged from time to time ... but this is a crucial feature that I need to test.

Hope you guys can help.

Greetings

Answer (score 2):

So I found the problem:

basically you have to approve the payment before you get a notification.

[What is wrong with my paypal process to receive webhook notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615542/what-is-wrong-with-my-paypal-process-to-receive-webhook-notifications)

On your return Site, you just need to send an approval and there your webhook is triggered!

Comment: this answer is so rare, it should be stated in every topic regarding paypal webhooks. It indeed requires to send payment executor in order to get PayPal webhook triggered. I will make an answer with a little code too.

Answer (score 0):

As @MollocH has figure out, in order to trigger PayPal's webhooks you must approve the payment once you redirected to your website.

```
    $payerId = // 'PayerID' from the GET query;
    $paymentId = // 'paymentId' from the GET query;

    $apiContext = // you know where to get this from
    $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);

    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayerId($payerId);

    try
    {
        $payment = $payment->execute($execution, $context);

        // redirect user to success message or so
    }
    catch(\Exception $error)
    {

    }
```